# Excel sniffing, regex, and substring matching

Tags: python, regex, csv, xlrd

I have this code that searches for a "phrase" in a "column" within all of the spreadsheets within a directory, and then outputs the matching date, time, and position into an "output.csv" (the position is on the same line, but the date and time are in the same row, 0-7 rows up from the 'phrase' row position). I need for it to be able to find the "phrase" within a cell, but right now, it only works for exact matches. If a cell in column 20 contained "phrase one", the example below wouldn't write the to the output file.

```
import os
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
import datetime
from datetime import time
import csv

# edit these params
outputfile = 'output.csv'
phrase = 'phrase'
column = 20

rootdir = '.'


def writeToCSV(datalist,outputfile):
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
        for sublist in datalist:
            for item in sublist:
                f.write(item + ',')
            f.write('\n')

def getdata(filename,row):
    # print(row)
    # print(filename,'filename')
    wb = open_workbook(filename)
    items = []
    for sheet in wb.sheets():
        number_of_rows = sheet.nrows
        number_of_columns = sheet.ncols

        rows = []
        # print(filename,' file')
        for row1 in range(row,row-10, -1):
            # print()
            if row1 >= 0 and row1 < number_of_rows:
                rowNo = sheet.cell(row1, 2).value
                try :
                    if rowNo != '' and int(rowNo):
                        datetime1 = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(sheet.cell_value(rowx=row1, colx=0), wb.datemode))
                        date_values = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(sheet.cell_value(rowx=row1, colx=1), wb.datemode)
                        time_value = time(*date_values[3:])
                        # print(time_value)
                        items.append(str(rowNo))
                        items.append(str(datetime1))
                        items.append(str(time_value))
                        # items[str(rowNo)]= str(datetime1)+'-'+str(time_value)
                        break
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
                    # print(e)
    # print(items)
    return items

def extractData(filename,searchString,column):
    wb = open_workbook(filename)
    dataList = []
    for sheet in wb.sheets():
        number_of_rows = sheet.nrows
        number_of_columns = sheet.ncols
        items = []
        rows = []
        for row in range(1, number_of_rows):
            rowdata = []
            for col in range(number_of_columns):
                value = (sheet.cell(row, col).value)
                if value == searchString :
                    if col == column :
                        data = getdata(filename,row)
                        dataList.append(data)

                        # print(value)
                # rowdata.append(value)

            # print(len(rowdata))
    return dataList

def main():
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            fullname =os.path.join(subdir, file)
            list = subdir.split('\\')
            date = ''
            if len(list) > 2 :
                date = list[1].split('-')[1] +'-'+ list[2]
            # print(date)
            # print(file)
            if date != '' :
                namelist = file.split('-')
                if len(namelist)> 2:
                    if (namelist[0] in date) and (namelist[1] in date):
                        # print(file)
                        data = extractData(fullname,phrase,column)
                        if len(data) > 0 :
                            writeToCSV(data,outputfile)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()  # call main method
```

I understand that regex can easily find substrings within a string, but I don't get exactly where to make the modification within the code. In a different language or if the code was written differently, I would try to add an if statement that would write the data to the output file if the string contained "phrase", but I can't determine where the code tries to qualify that the phrase matches the cell value. Any insight on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `extractData` you make the comparison `if value == searchString :`. That is where you check if the string `value` (from your Excel file) is the same as the `searchString` (your "pharse").
You can replace that with Pythons `searchString in value`. The line should look like `if searchString in value:` You do not need regex if you only looking for substrings.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that seem to be causing issues, but the main one might be that your extractData module has found your search string in a row in a specific sheet, and your getData module is using the same row in all of the sheets in the workbook, without validating whether every sheet goes up to that row. It would be better to pass along which sheet you found the search string in, and have "getData" just search that specific sheet.